# Bash No Longer Changes Directory

Tags: linux, bash

My bash shell will no longer change directory with cd. I noticed it earlier when working and found that any new shells I opened (terminal or xterm etc) would be stuck in the home directory and could not get out (already open terminals continued to work fine).

```
[~]$ pwd
/home/sys/dave
[~]$ cd /
[~]$ cd Documents/
[~]$ pwd
/home/sys/dave
[~]$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
[~]$ alias
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias vi='vim'
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

I thought it must be some weirdness I didn't have time to deal with such as a handler out of memory (having checked that cd wasn't aliased and using the builtin version).

So I (yes, I know) rebooted the machine.

Fresh boot, exactly the same problem.

CSH on the other hand works fine, so immediately after the snippet above:

```
[~]$ csh
[~]$ cd /
[/]$ pwd
/
[/]$ cd ~/Documents/
[~/Documents]$ pwd
/home/sys/dave/Documents
[~/Documents]$
```

I haven't installed anything new or performed any updates in the last few days and it was working fine until late this evening.

Ideas/assistance/HELP much appreciated!

** UPDATE **

So digging around I found this line in .bashrc

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="cd"
```

If I unset PROMPT_COMMAND then everything works as normal.

But... WTF. I didn't put this line in the .bashrc and everything was working perfectly until tonight. Should I just comment it out, manually unset it, or just burn the computer as a witch?

Comment: OS is CentOS 6.3 Final, Kernel is 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64, command-line expansion through tab if I put in a full directory name and type/more etc again if I put in a FQ file path work fine. If that helps.

Comment: If something on your system recently changed, and you are the only user and you didn't make that change, then perhaps your system has been compromised?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` to `cd` is a pretty common prank, if you didn't set it, and you're the only user, then yes, you've been compromised.

If friends have access though, this is a prank I've seen numerous times, talk with them.

Comment: Or if you're in an environment where you might have left your terminal unlocked. It depends on the corporate culture, but since unlocked terminals are a frowned upon practice, pranking between sysadmins is fairly common.

Comment: I think I've been pranked. +1 to my lab colleagues for a Linux prank. -1 to me for leaving the screen unlocked. Don't think I've been compromised, well at least I hope not - everything else looks well. Thanks to all for your answers.

Comment: Technically, this is still a compromise, even if it was done "for fun".  Depending on who you are and where you are, it could lead to you and/or your colleagues getting told off or worse, or it might be your responsibility to report the compromise to IT staff (by law).

Answer (score 0):

> If `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable is set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt. In other words, the contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command just before Bash displays a prompt:

```
[vivek@vivek-desktop man]$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo Yahooo"
Yahooo
[vivek@vivek-desktop man]$ date
Tue Oct 20 23:50:01 IST 2009
Yahooo
```

[source](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Changing_bash_prompt#PROMPT_COMMAND_variable)

`cd` without arguments returns to the home directory (handy!).

`.bashrc` gets executed when spawning each shell, that's why the old terminals were unaffected.